# Type of Multi-Value Parameter

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I was just wondering if anyone knew what type a Multi-Value parameter is within SSRS. So by this I mean when you Right Click a parameter and have "Allow Multiple Values" what does that return?

A list, an array, an arrayList?

I'm having some trouble using one of these values within a custom code function and just want to make sure I'm using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone interested this will return an Array.